# Screen blinks after sleep

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, suspend, screen

The screen of my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 (AMD Ryzen 5 4600H  (NVIDIA GTX 1650 4GB/120Hz Refresh Display), 82EY00UAIN ) starts [blinking](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYICMZDvDQVYNEWLRcOtXYcloYKXGCmc/view) once I turn it back on from sleep mode. I have dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, I face this problem only while I am using Ubuntu. Restarting the laptop will stop the blinking.This issue started less than a month ago. I tried installing the NVIDIA driver using the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, still the issue persist.

Could anyone suggest any fix for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From today, even after restarting, the screen keeps on blinking.

Comment: I guess this is due to the NVIDIA driver. I am currently using NVIDIA driver 510.47.03. Can anyone suggest a better version or driver. I tried `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin` but it doesn't seem to work. I changed the GPU to Performance mode from On-Demand, now it is better (now the screen blinking stops after restart).